# Run R script on Amazon EC2

Tags: r, performance, amazon-ec2

I am working with large datasets in R and some of the computations are too heavy for my machine in terms of RAM (cannot allocate vector of size n Mb).

```
sessionInfo()
```

> R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>
> locale:
>   [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252
>   [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
>   [5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252
>
> attached base packages:
>   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:
>    [1] MASS_7.3-35      lubridate_1.3.3  nlstools_1.0-0   stringr_0.6.2    numbers_0.5-2    plyr_1.8.1
>    [7] simecol_0.8-4    deSolve_1.11     Quandl_2.4.0     xts_0.9-7        zoo_1.7-11       data.table_1.9.4
>   [13] RODBC_1.3-10
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>    [1] bitops_1.0-6    chron_2.3-45    digest_0.6.8    grid_3.1.2      lattice_0.20-29 memoise_0.2.1
>    [7] Rcpp_0.11.4     RCurl_1.95-4.5  reshape2_1.4.1  RJSONIO_1.3-0   tools_3.1.2

I have access to an Amazon EC2 external server with up to 30 GB RAM which should be enough. My question is how I can run an R script on this external server using my local machine? Is there a function for this?

Answer (score 1):

you would have to put script on the external machine and then run it:

```
ssh user_name@123.321.123.123 'my_script.r'
```

Much nicer way of doing that would be to use [RStudio server](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552306-Getting-Started).